# is there a third-party javascript library/social media sharing service that can use custom query parameters for the share link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, share, social-media

**The Goal and the Problem**

I am working on a sharing solution in our React-based video and audio search apps. My goal is that when sharing a single item from a search result set to a social media app (e.g. Facebook, Messenger, LinkedIn, Twitter) and then clicked by someone else, the user lands within our search app/experience with only a single result showing (the shared item), which is done using query parameters in our search apps. Imagine using Google image search, and creating a little share icon on each search result so that when hovered/clicked/tapped and shared to social media then clicked by someone on said social media channel, the user lands in Google image search with just that single shared item in the result set.

We've been challenged to find a third party solution that uses custom query parameters for share links on each search result to help us achieve our goal. They all seem to use the base url structure (`window.location.origin` + `window.location.pathname` e.g. `https://www.clipstock.com/audio`) which won't work properly to show a single search result within our search experience which needs a query parameter as shown in the example below. Note: this url approach works fine for sharing a full page "node" with just the single video or audio result on the page, which we're also doing separately.

We've built a custom solution in our React based search apps that does achieve our goal of having the user land within our search app with just a single search result although we expect our custom solution to break if/when sharing urls in social apps update which seems to happen yearly or so. We figure a third party JavaScript library or third party social share service will fix these issues faster and cheaper without our development time if/when the sharing URLs break.

Has anyone seen a third party solution to this?

**Examples**

Example link for landing on a single search result in our audio search app, achieved by the search query q="Reunited" in the url: https://www.clipstock.com/audio?q=%22Reunited%22&size=n_12_n

Example share link of our custom solution for sharing the above search result on Facebook today, which seems to change by the year (note the `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=` part of the url, which is the part that may break from Facebook updates): https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.clipstock.com/audio?q=%22Reunited%22&size=n_12_n

Example link of a single video clip node page, which works well with any third party sharing solution, although isn't the goal of this question which is to land in our search app(s) with just the single shared item in the result set which is achieved using query parameters as seen in the examples above: https://www.clipstock.com/clip/young-male-swimmer-diving-starting-block-olympic-size-pool-lanes-slow-motion

The below approach to sharing works for us, although is the custom sharing solution we created that may break over the years. In this example, on mobile, the Facebook app opens, and on non-mobile, the Facebook web app opens, which is our goal. Either of the Facebook share urls (and the share urls for each other social media app like Messenger, LinkedIn, Twitter) could change over time since they're essentially API integrations and we think it would be cheaper & faster to invest in a third party sharing solution than to monitor for these breaks and fix the breaks ourselves.

Note: some setup code in the below example is not included such as the DrupalContext. We aren't getting errors in the code, rather, we're looking for a third-party solution so that we don't have to maintain custom code.

```
  const drupalContext = useContext(DrupalContext);
  const queryString = type === "sfx" ? drupalContext.sfxQueryString : "";
  const baseUrl = window.location.origin.concat(window.location.pathname);
  const sharingLink =
    type === "video"
      ? baseUrl.concat("?q=").concat(nodeId)
      : baseUrl
          .concat("?q=")
          .concat(encodeURI('"'))
          .concat(encodeURI(title))
          .concat(encodeURI('"'))
          .concat(queryString);


  const shareViaFacebook = () => {
    let shareUrl = "";
    if (platform?.os?.family === ("iOS" || "Android" || "Windows Phone")) {
      shareUrl = "fb://share/?link=" + sharingLink;
    } else {
      shareUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + sharingLink;
    }
    window.open(shareUrl);
  };
```

We've created similar `shareVia...` methods for each social media app we're sharing to which currenly consists of Facebook, Messenger, LinkedIn, Twitter, Email, and "Copy Link". Email and "Copy Link" are what we're going to fall back to using if we can't find a reliable third-party solution (removing Facebook, Messenger, LinkedIn, and Twitter sharing options) since Email and "Copy Link" reliably work and we don't expect these two options to break over time.